# Rmarkdown copy non-generated images as assets

Tags: r-markdown

I have an Rmarkdown files with markdown links to images (not generated in R). For example;

```
![](./data/method1/results/bla.png)

 And results show:

![](./data/method2/distances/average/avg.png)
...
```

When I render to HTML using `self_contained:true`, the resulting html file is portable and all is good. But when I use `self_contained:false`, the html file is not portable as the images are in different places. Is there an option to gather all the referenced images and copy them to a local assets directory relative to the Rmd file like `./images/` for example?

I am not using `knitr::include_graphics()` or manually copying them, because there are hundreds of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution.

```r
library(stringr)

#' @title portify
#' @description Copies markdown liked files in Rmd as portable assets and renames markdown paths in Rmd
#' @param path <Character> Path to Rmd file
#' @param path_out <Character> Path to new Rmd file
#' @param dirname <Character> Name for portable images directory
#' @param overwrite_dir <Logical> Should the portable images directory be overwritten if it exists?
#' @param pattern <Character> Regular expression pattern used to find markdown image links in Rmd
#' @details Makes Rmd with markdown linked images portable. Images are copied over from source location to a local directory named dirname keeping the source directory structure. The image paths are corrected in the Rmd file and a new Rmd file is created.
#' @examples 
#' \donotrun{
#' portify("report.Rmd")
#' }
#' 
portify <- function(path, path_out=NULL, dirname="markdown_images", overwrite_dir=FALSE, pattern="!\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\(([^'\"\\)]*)\\)"){
  
  x <- readLines(path)
  pos <- str_which(x, pattern)
  path_from <- str_match(x[pos], pattern)[,2]
  dir_to <- file.path(dirname(path), dirname)
  
  # remove dir recursively if it exists and overwrite_dir=T
  if(dir.exists(dir_to) & overwrite_dir){
    unlink(dir_to,recursive=TRUE)
    message(paste("Removing directory", dir_to,"."))
  }
  
  # create dir if it doesn't exist
  if(!dir.exists(dir_to)) {
    dir.create(dir_to)
    message(paste("Directory", dir_to,"created."))
  }
  
  # expects images to use relative links in Rmd
  path_to <- file.path(dir_to, path_from)
  subdir_to <- dirname(path_to)
  
  # remove subdir recursively if it exists and overwrite_dir=T
  if(overwrite_dir) invisible(lapply(subdir_to, function(x) if(dir.exists(x)) unlink(x, recursive=TRUE)))
  
  # create subdir if it doesn't exist
  invisible(lapply(subdir_to, function(x) if(!dir.exists(x)) dir.create(x, recursive=TRUE)))
  
  # copy files from source to destination
  file.copy(from=path_from, to=path_to, copy.date=TRUE)

  # replace old links with new links
  path_md <- paste0("![](", path_to,")")
  x[pos] <- str_replace(x[pos], pattern, path_md)
  
  if(is.null(path_out)) path_out <- str_replace(path,".Rmd","-port.Rmd")
  writeLines(x, path_out)
  message(paste(path_out, "created."))
}
```

***Warning!** It worked for my use case, but it could fail spectacularly for your use case.*